# Excel - comparing a cell with a concatenated value in an IF statement

Tags: excel, concatenation

I understand that `CONCATENATE()` returns a string but hopefully the formula below should help provide some context and what I'm trying to achieve:

I need the cell to say `YES` or `NO` depending on whether a date is within a specific range.

- V3 = `1.1`
- C5 = `01/01/2014`
- D5 = `01/02/2014`

```
=IF(AND(V$3>=CONCATENATE(DAY($C5),".",MONTH($C5)),
   V$3<=CONCATENATE(DAY($D5),".",MONTH($D5))),"YES","NO")
```

Comment: So V3 represents Day.Month? Is that fixed? I agree to some extent with Dave's advice to keep the data as numbers but then 20th January = 20.1 and 20th October = 20.10 - kept as numbers those will be the same thing. It would be better with V3 as Month.Day e.g. for 3rd November 11.03 or for 30th November 11.30

Comment: V3 represents Month.Day - sorry I should have mentioned that...

Comment: @hs0 I think that the point of Barry still holds: 1.10 would mean 10th January, but converted to number would be 1.1 (or 1st January)!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare numbers why use concatenate? Just keep them as numbers like so:

```
=IF(AND(V$3>=DAY($C5)+(MONTH($C5)/10),V$3<=DAY($D5)+(MONTH($D5)/10)),"Yes","No")
```

EDIT:

It's difficult to come up with a solution for because your question is not very clear. Is your problem that you have a decimal number that represents a month and a day and you want to know if it lies between to dates, however because your decimal number has nothing to represent the year you want to exclude year from the comparison and just base it on month and day?

If so then try this:

```
=IF(AND(DATE(1900,INT(V$3),(V$3 - INT(V$3))*10)>=DATE(1900,MONTH($C5),DAY($C5)),DATE(1900,INT(V$3),(V$3 - INT(V$3))*10)<=DATE(1900,MONTH($D5),DAY($D5))),"Yes","No")
```

This converts all three elements to be dates with a year of 1900.

Comment: ....but DAY($C5)+MONTH($C5/10) could be the same for different dates, e.g. 3rd December and 4th February both equal 4.2

Comment: Thanks @Dave, for my purposes the concept of your formula works (I've just reshuffled it):

`code`=IF(AND(Y$3>=MONTH($C8)+(DAY($C8)/10), Y$3<=MONTH($D8)+(DAY($D8)/10)),"Yes","No")`code`

Comment: ...but that still won't work in all cases, surely, because DAY can be > 10 so MONTH(C8)+DAY(C8)/10 could be the same for different dates. 5th March = 3.5, 15th Feb = 3.5, 25th Jan = 3.5....etc. You need to divide the day by 100, so those would be respectively 3.05, 2.15 and 1.25 - Y3 would have to work on the same basis as per my comment on your question

Comment: Yes thinking about I should be multiplying the fraction representing the month by 100 and the months should should run in the sequence 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06 .. 0.12. There is something very wrong storing date information this way.

Answer (score 0):

If V3 represents Month.Day such that 1.1 is actually January 10th, then in cell E5 use this formula to convert it to a date (and format cell E5 as date):

```
=--TEXT(V$3*100&YEAR($C5),"00\/00\/0000")
```

Then the comparison formula becomes:

```
=IF(AND($C5<=$E5,$D5>=$E5),"YES","NO")
```

If you can't have a helper cell, then here's the full formula:

```
=IF(AND($C5<=--TEXT(V$3*100&YEAR($C5),"00\/00\/0000"),$D5>=--TEXT(V$3*100&YEAR($C5),"00\/00\/0000")),"YES","NO")
```